# Symlink for one process

Tags: linux, audio, symbolic-link

I have a program which expects a legacy sound device (oss) to be present (`/dev/dsp`).
The system I'm working have several of these present (`/dev/dspX`).

How would I go about creating a program / process specific symlink? - i.e. symlinking `/dev/dsp2` to `/dev/dsp`, but only for this specific process.

Comment: (1) Which audio system are you actually running? Pulseaudio? Alsa without pulseaudio? Real OSS? The first two have ways to emulate OSS, and to select which device is which. (2) Which program are you talking about? Most OSS programs have ways to configure which OSS devices they are using. (3) If `/dev/dsp` already exists, you won't be able to pretend it doesn't, unless you invest a *lot* of effort like a `chroot` with it's own `/dev` dir.

Comment: `/dev/dsp` does not exist, only `/dev/dspX` devices do.

The system is running pulseaudio, but I'm not looking for a specific system for this audio-case, but rather a generic one.

Comment: The program is an old video-game, does not support picking OSS device, and I cannot recompile or otherwise change the executable.

Comment: I am aware that a simple symlink from `/dev/dsp2` to `/dev/dsp` works in my case (I'm currently using this), but I'm looking for a general solution to process specific symlinks, not just for a specific solution to this issue.

Comment: If you are using pulseaudio, try starting the video game app with `padsp -n appname app arg1 arg2 ...`. Then you can configure pulseaudio to provide the correct source/sink for that app. Yes, I'm aware this doesn't answer your question about a process specific symlinks (and I'm not even sure if such an option exists at all).

Comment: @dirkt The game isn't aware of pulseaudio, the game interacts directly with `/dev/dsp`, and it's hardcoded this way. Will this still work even then?

Comment: Yes. `padsp` is made exactly for legacy applications that are not aware of pulseaudio, and only intereact directly with `/dev/dsp`. It does so by using some preload-magic, and interecepting system calls. (However, it doesn't work completely if your application uses `select` - you'll see a few bogus streams, but it still sort of works, at least for the one application I tried that did that).